# c++ Use std::enable_if to conditionally add getters to a variadic variant template

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to add specializations for the case where my variant has any of `int`, `float`, `bool`, and others as template arguments.

**My attempt so far is:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types>
struct variant : std::variant<Types...> {

    using std::variant<Types...>::variant;

    template<typename T>
    const T& get() const { return std::get<T>(*this); }

#define VARGET(X) typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<Types, X>::value ||  ... ), X>::type get_##X() const { return get<X>(); }

    VARGET(int)
    VARGET(float)
    VARGET(double)
    VARGET(bool)
    using std_string = std::string;
    VARGET(std_string)
};

int main()
{

    variant<int, float, bool> var = 3;
    std::cout << var.get_int() << std::endl;

    variant<int, float, bool> var2 = 0.1f;
    std::cout << var2.get_float() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But on gcc 9 this gives the error:

```
error: failed requirement 'std::is_same<int, double>::value || std::is_same<float, double>::value || std::is_same<bool, double>::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
```

**Why this confuses me**:

From my understanding of SFINAE, when one of the arguments is one of the specified types, the macro template evaluates to: (For the example of int)

`std::enable_if<(std::is_same<Types, int>::value ||  ... ), int>::type` evaluates to `int`

so the expression becomes `int get_int() const { std::get<int>(*this) }`

And if it is not one of the specified types:

`std::enable_if<(std::is_same<Types, size_t>::value ||  ... ), size_t>::type` evaluates to nothing

so the expression becomes `get_size_t() const { std::get<size_t>(*this) }`

This is invalid syntax because the function does not have a return type, but because of SFINAE this should still compile because of other substitutions of X do produce valid syntax.

What is wrong with my code, and is there a way to get the result I desire?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I am receiving when trying to compile your code differs from yours, see on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hLjo9j); I receive the error "`no type named type in ...`" which I would have expected, as SFINAE does not apply in this case.

SFINAE would apply for instance in a function call if there is a substitution which whould cause a failure. Nothing were to be substituted in the function, the code is always wrong / always correct depending on the struct's template arguments.

When creating the struct, it is either always malformed, or always well-formed. You might be able to work around this by imposing an artificial substitution in the function:

```
template <bool f=false>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same<Types, int>::value ||  ...  ||f ), int> get_int() const { return get<int>(); }
```

Then it should compile fine.

[Substitution occurs in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

- all types used in the function type (which includes return type and the types of all parameters)
- all types used in the template parameter declarations
- all expressions used in the function type
- all expressions used in a template parameter declaration
  (since C++11)
- all expressions used in the explicit specifier
  (since C++20)

The reason why the code is condensed best in the fact, that 
`std::enable_if_t<false, int> func() {}` will always fail to compile.

Comment: I came to a similar solution at about the same time you answered this, but I prefer your solution. I have tested this and it works, even with my macro!. It compiles when I want it to, and gives a compile error if you try to call a disabled function. Annoyingly the intellisense in Qt Creator still suggests the disabled functions, but that's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.

The SFINAE function needs to be a template with a default template argument. i.e:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types>
struct variant : std::variant<Types...> {

    using std::variant<Types...>::variant;

    template<typename T>
    const T& get() const { return std::get<T>(*this); }

#define VARGET(X) template<typename T = X> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Types, T> ||  ... ), X> get_##X() const { return get<X>(); }

    VARGET(int)
    VARGET(float)
    VARGET(double)
    VARGET(bool)
    using std_string = std::string;
    VARGET(std_string)
};

int main()
{

    variant<int, float, bool> var = 4;
    std::cout << var.get_int() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << var.get_std_string() << std::endl; compile error

    variant<int, std::string> var2 = "hello";
    std::cout << var2.get_std_string() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```